# I am looking for the Vertx JDBC SQLite Driver

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, driver, vert.x

I am currently looking for some informations about the way to call the right SQLite driver class to use the JDBC Client.
I use Maven and have currently this in my **POM.xml** ,

```
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-jdbc-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I did put this to create the sql Client.

```
     JsonObject config = new JsonObject()
                .put("url", "jdbc:sqlite:"+DB_PATH)
                .put("driver_class", "org.sqlite.jdbcDriver")
                .put("max_pool_size", 30);

    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
            SQLClient client = JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, config);
```

Did anyone already succeeded in using SQLite for the **async** JDBC Client? 

(edit: I insist on the fact that I would like to keep the async jdbc client)

 Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to be sure, did you add the sqlite driver dependency to your pom file?

Comment: thanks you, that was the part that I missed!! 
My project is working fine now, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Vertx JDBC client is not enough, as @tsegismont correctly mentioned in his comment. You still need the actual driver:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.19.3</version>
</dependency>
```